# document.onclick only execute for a specific div

Tags: javascript, html

I've this code below:

```js
document.onclick = function () {
    console.log("Hello"); 
}
```

```html
<div class="label-search">Click me</div>
```

I want to execute the *console.log* only when I click in this `div class="label-search"`without add `onclick` in div.

Thank you.

Comment: it works. Where's the problem?

Comment: @DaFois read the question one more time.

Comment: What do you mean by 'without add onclick in div.' ?

Comment: I know, but I've several div's and I want to use this but only for this div

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy still don't understand... there's any onclich attr on the div

Comment: @Oen44 its not the same thing :/

Comment: @DaFois that's his question, he don't know how to attach an onclick to a div :-)

Comment: @KmDroid Just saw you don't want to use `onclick` attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the element you want to set the click functionality of using it's `onclick` property. At the moment you are adding it to the entire `document`.

In this case you can use:

`document.querySelector('.label-search')`

to get your div which has the class `label-search`, and then use `.onclick` to set its click functionality.

See working example below:

```js
document.querySelector('.label-search').onclick = function() {
  console.log("Hello");
}
```

```html
<div class="label-search">Label Search</div>
```

Using this you can avoid adding the `onclick` attribute to your `div`

Comment: @ygorbunkov actually, not exactly. It will print "hello" into the console for the first `div` with the class `label-search` when clicked. Not all the divs with the class `label-search`

Answer (score 2):

Select the div to apply the onclick to that div
Using

```
document.getElementsByClassName
```

```js
document.getElementsByClassName('label-search')[0].onclick = function () {
    console.log("Hello"); 
}
```

```html
<div class="label-search">aa</div>
```

Using `querySelector`

```js
document.querySelector('.label-search').onclick = function () {
    console.log("Hello"); 
}
```

```html
<div class='label-search'>aa</div>
```

Comment: Bad example, better use `querySelector` or `id` and `getElementById`.

Comment: He may have other div's of the same class (above that one as well as below) and all of them will be treated in the same way if you go second way and only first one (not necessarily, as desired) if you go first way.

Answer (score 1):

You have to target the div element to execute the function on clicking on it. You can use [`Document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

> The Document method `querySelector()` returns the first Element within the document that matches the specified selector, or group of selectors. If no matches are found, `null` is returned.

```js
document.querySelector('.label-search').onclick = function () {
    console.log("Hello"); 
}
```

```html
<div class="label-search">Click</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign unique attribute (id) to your element: `<div class="label-search" id="searchdiv"></div>` and attach event listener to your specific element:

```js
document.querySelector('#clickmediv').addEventListener('click',function(){console.log("Hello!");});
```

```css
.label-search {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="label-search" id="clickmediv">Click me</div>
```

Comment: `querySelector` is pointless in this case. Just use `getElementById`.

Comment: @Oen44 in the OP there's no id, he's using a class.

Comment: Why? Does it work slower? I just prefer it as a universal wrapper to any type of selector.

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy On the other hand, he stated 'only when I click this div', so he might have other div's of the same class at the same page.

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy Did you even read that code? He is using `querySelector` using `id`. It's wrong!

Comment: @Oen44 yup, I totally didn't read his code xD But I was talking in general about the other answers and why you shouldn't change the HTML

Comment: Your assertion that OP _needs_ to add an id is wrong though.

Comment: @Andy As I already noticed above, he needs (as stated in the question body and his further comments) to fire hello-message upon clicking one particular div (not all of the class, not even first of the class). Is there some other way to do so?

Comment: Based on the code __with which we're presented__ `querySelector` is fine. If you want to go into detail about what happens in the event there are elements with the same class use your answer to do that, but you can't justify "need" here based on the code you've been given without further explanation.

Comment: It's like the guy is standing on the road with a tire blown on his wheel and asking for help in a very straightforward terms and you sit in his car, drive two miles further to show him how he can possibly go wrong with that flat tire instead of simply fixing what's broken and addressing the very obvious problem he described.

Comment: Except `querySelector` isn't broken in the OP's code. Your analogy makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

Other answers used `querySelector` and `getElementsByClassName`. If you want to take in consideration `performance`, you could do something like this:

```js
let element = document.getElementById("elementToBeClicked");
element.onclick = () => console.log("I was clicked !!!!");
```

```html
<div id="elementToBeClicked">Click Me Please!</div>
```

> [The Document method getElementById() returns an Element object representing the element whose id property matches the specified string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)

I advise you to use `getElementById` because is faster then using `queryselector` (check [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnjavascript/comments/356k1v/confused_on_queryselector_and_getelementbyid/) to see the performance differences and test your self [here](https://jsperf.com/different-types-of-selecting)).

Also, if you don't know what is arrow function `() => console.log("I Was Clicked!!!")` you can check in [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/es6-arrow-functions-new-fat-concise-syntax-javascript/) a nice explanation.

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy I'm only presenting an alternative and explain why I think is better. I know that is been using class. But a solution with `queryselector` already was answered so. And what is the point of stackoverflow? Is not to share knowledge?

Comment: That reddit thread is from 3 years ago. There have been vast improvements to JS engines in the meantime.

Comment: Yes  @Andy, but you can test in your updated browser in https://jsperf.com/different-types-of-selecting the same results that that reddit post pointing out

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by below 3 methods:

1. User querySelector:

   document.querySelector('.label-search').onclick = function () {
       console.log("Hello"); 
   }
2. GetElementByClassName

   document.getElementsByClassName('label-search')[0].onclick = function () {
       console.log("Hello"); 
   }
3. If you can replace class with id 
   class="label-search" replace with id="label-search"

   let element = document.getElementById("label-search");
   element.onclick = () => console.log("Hello");